# Is it possible to transpile local modules from node_module?

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, karma-webpack

I have 2 typescript projects which contain few classes. I have added Project1's dependency in the Project2 in package.json

```
{
  "name": "Project2",
  "dependencies": {
    "@Project1": "file:../Project1/dist"
  }
}
```

Both the project are built using

> "target": "es5", "module": "es2015",

I am using [Karma-Webpack](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/karma-webpack) for setting up test environment for the projects. To transpile the code I have used [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) (with preset: es2015) instead of ts-loader. It transpiles the code from the Project2 but the code from Project1 located in node_modules is not getting transpiled. Due to that it throws below error when the test is run

> Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR   Uncaught SyntaxError:
> Unexpected token export   at spec.bundle.js:80972

I was wondering is it possible to transpile local modules from node_modules using webpack?

**Note:** if I change the module type to "commonjs", it works but this not the solution I am looking for.

Any suggestions???

Comment: the code in the node_modules should already be transpiled.

Comment: Okay. is there any way to pre-process it using any karma-preprocessors? similar to other code?

Comment: well.. if you are using gulp or grunt you could just build the projects. But it would be a really messy way of handling things.

Comment: Got the solution, you can configure webpack to transpile the local dependent module (placed inside node_module) using babel-loader. Thanks

Comment: Awesome, would you care to post an answer as well? In case other people have the same issue? :)

Comment: Sure, added the answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I faced this error since I am using es2015 to compile the parent module. If you use commonjs, you wont face this issue.

You can transpile the node module code by adding below in webpack configurations in karma.config.file.

```
webpack: {
            resolve: {
                extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
            },

            module: {
                loaders: [
                    {
                        // This will transpile Typescript files
                        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        loader: "babel-loader" + "?presets[]=es2015" + "!ts-loader",
                    },
                    {
                        // This will transpile ES2015 javascript files
                        test: /\.js(x?)$/,
                        include: [
                            path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/<<YOUR MODULE NAME>>")
                        ],
                        loader: "babel-loader" + "?presets[]=es2015"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

Now, Webpack will transpile both JS/TS code using babel-loader.